# Removing the space occupied by the hidden forms

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to display a text field on selecting the different values from a combo box option.

html file

```
<select id="topic_type" onchange="func_type()">
    <option id="d"> D</option>
    <option id="o">O</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function func_type() 
{
    var elem = document.getElementById("topic_type");

    if(elem.value == "D") 
    {
        document.getElementById("form_d").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("form_o").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    } 
    else if(elem.value == "O")
    {
        document.getElementById("form_o").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("form_d").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
</script>
```

this code is working fine. But my problem is that the *form* is only hidden so it takes the space ie. when i choose different option text field appears but there is a space due to the hidden *form* is there any option by which i can remove that space

Comment: try to reduce your code size and don't copy same lines two times because size really matters in client side

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `display` instead of `visibility` as such:

```
if(elem.value == "D") {
    document.getElementById("form_d").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("form_o").style.display = 'none'; 
} else if(elem.value == "O") {
    document.getElementById("form_o").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("form_d").style.display = 'none';
}
```

Or using jQuery if you're interested you can use the `.show()` and `.hide()`:

```
if(elem.value == "D") {
    $("#form_d").show();
    $("#form_o").hide(); 
} else if(elem.value == "O") {
    $("#form_o").show();
    $("#form_d").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 2 option elements to deal with and plan on never expanding that, then ok.  But if for some reason you plan on expanding your options and just want to keep your code short and clean, you can track down the selected value of $(this)...

The jQuery:

```
function package() {
    $('#topic_type').on("change",function() {
      mthissel =  $(this).find("option:selected");
      mthissel.css({display:'block'}); //or 'none'
      $(this).find('option:not(:selected)').css({display:'none'});  //or 'block' dependent on your preference :)
    });
}

$(function() {
  package();
});
```

The HTML:

```
<select id="topic_type">
    <option id="d">D</option>
    <option id="o">O</option>
    <!--go ahead and add more <option values here-->
</select>
```

And my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/blackhawx/czDG9/1/) to show it in action